# Rename a file within a custom Vue-Cli template

Tags: vuejs2

I'm writing a custom [vue-cli template](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli#user-content-custom-templates). I want to be able to rename one of the files within the template based on the users answers to the "prompts" section of meta.json. The [docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli#user-content-custom-templates) mention that you can register custom metalsmith plugins via the "metalsmith" property in meta.json. I assume this would be the right place to rename a file, but how can I get access the users answer to the "promts" from here?

Note: The docs also mention a "complete" handler than can run code when the template rendering has completed, and this handler gets the users prompt data as an argument. Unfortunately, the cwd when this function is called is the template directory, not the output directory which makes renaming the file in the output from here messy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `__the_question__` ?
for exemple, lets say you have a question like 'name' and you answer 'mytodolist'  to it.

Then, if inside the template structure you have a folder or file named `__name__` it will be changed to `mytodolist` instead..

The problem I've found is, it seems it works only on the first level or the root of the template, if you have sub folders using _**something** it won't work.

In another words, inside a file, you must use {{name}} and it will be changed to the answer, and for files/folders you must use **name** instead of {{ name }}.

p.s: That`s why I like most the python template lib called [cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter)

UPDATE:
To make it work, you must add extra code inside the meta.js to rename files or folder, for example:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function onerror(err) {
    if ( err ) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
}

module.exports = {
  "prompts": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "label": "Project name"
    }
  },
  "complete": function (data, {logger, chalk}) {
    const base = data.inPlace ? '' : data.destDirName + '/'
    fs.rename(`${base}__name__`, `${base}${data.name}`, onerror)
    console.log('done!')
  },
}
```